# Recent references establishing connections between stabilizer error correction and entanglement distillation procedures

Tags: entanglement, error-correction, resource-request

I know some concrete entanglement distillation protocols (from [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4165)).
I also know there are connections between error-correction codes and entanglement distillation (again [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4165) but also [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.54.3824)).

However, the references I provided are a bit old, and I wonder if there are more recent references nicely explaining the connections between the two.

In particular, I am looking for connections through the stabilizer formalism of error-correction.

Importantly, I would like to avoid references which are explaining the connection through a very mathematical computer science perspective (for instance, I think I know well the stabilizer formalism but I am much less used to the general mathematical theory of CSS codes: I am much more on the physics than computer science part of the field). I know the basics of ZX-calculus so I could understand papers using simple properties of ZX.

[This topic](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/33661/understanding-entanglement-distillation-via-stabilizer-codes) is very related to my question but there are not (much) references to recent papers/reviews on the topic (I am currently studying the answer given there).